# Taking save/download screen/creating an image using knockout.js

Tags: image, knockout.js, printing, screenshot

We have an mvc app built using knockout.js and there is a outer frame and then it has several panels inside. They use high charts too within the panels.

What I have don't know is how to do download image/screen when a user clicks a button from the outer frame or even from on the panel, of an existing panel after its loaded .  I can raise an event when the button is clicked but now I don't know how to capture the already loaded panel and then convert it into an image file.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.
Sarah

Comment: That's difficult to answer unless you can show us some of the code you've written

Comment: Sorry never got back to you on this. I have made some progress and added some code to this post, if you can help here please.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221267/using-htmltocanvas-for-my-webpage-but-highcharts-are-coming-partial